# Formatting tempTextField in Java . 

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, coding-style

Okay, so here is my latest challenge. I am writing this for school. So far, I have been able to get the GUI to function 'basically' the way I want it to, but I have run into some trouble integrating a Formatted Text Field. What I cannot understand is why the program won't accept 5.75 for an interest rate - it defaults to 5 - when the calculation module worked fine in a different program before I plugged its logic into my GUI program. That being said, I am posting my code, and any input would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * MortgageCalculatorGUI.java
 *
 * Created on Dec 18, 2011, 9:01:24 PM
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Roy Kosch
 */
public class MortgageCalculatorGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form MortgageCalculatorGUI */
    public MortgageCalculatorGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        tempTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tempTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tempTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        interestLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        termLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        loanLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        backButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        quitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        paymentLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Kosch Mortgage Calculator");

        tempTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                tempTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tempTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                tempTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        interestLabel.setText("Interest");

        termLabel.setText("Loan Term");

        loanLabel.setText("Loan Amount");

        calculateButton.setText("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                calculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        backButton.setText("Go Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                backButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        quitButton.setText("QUIT");
        quitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                quitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        paymentLabel.setText("Your payment is:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                        .addComponent(tempTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(interestLabel))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(115, 115, 115)
                        .addComponent(quitButton))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(tempTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(tempTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(termLabel)
                            .addComponent(loanLabel)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(paymentLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(calculateButton)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(backButton)))))
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {backButton, calculateButton, interestLabel, loanLabel, quitButton, tempTextField1, tempTextField2, tempTextField3, termLabel});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tempTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(interestLabel))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tempTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(termLabel))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tempTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(loanLabel))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(paymentLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(calculateButton)
                    .addComponent(backButton))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(quitButton)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {backButton, calculateButton, interestLabel, loanLabel, quitButton, tempTextField1, tempTextField2, tempTextField3, termLabel});

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void tempTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void tempTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        {
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        double principalLoan = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField3.getText())));
        double loanInterest = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField1.getText())));
        double loanTerm = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField2.getText())));

        double compoundMultiplier = loanInterest/1200;
        double termMultiplier = loanTerm*(12);
        double exponent = -1*(termMultiplier);

        double a = 1+compoundMultiplier;
        double b = Math.pow(a,exponent);
        double c = 1 - b;
        double d = compoundMultiplier/c;

        double mortgagePayment = d*principalLoan;


        paymentLabel.setText("Your Payment is: $" + formatter.format(mortgagePayment));

        }
    }                                               

    private void backButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                          

    private void quitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculatorGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculatorGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculatorGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MortgageCalculatorGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MortgageCalculatorGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton backButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton calculateButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel interestLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel loanLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel paymentLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton quitButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tempTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tempTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tempTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel termLabel;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) may help...

Comment: While it's not technically a programming mistake, can you remove the full qualification of your class names and use imports instead? It makes your code a lot harder to read. Good programmers write code that humans can understand. Bad ones write code that computers can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem** : Unnecessary casting to `int` .

**Solution** : Don't unnecessarily cast these to `int`.

```
    double principalLoan = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField3.getText());
    double loanInterest  = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField1.getText());
    double loanTerm      = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField2.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a [formatted text field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) in your code. But I find the following line

```
double loanInterest = (int) ((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField1.getText())));
```

where you cast your `Double` into a `int`. Maybe you mean

```
double loanInterest = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField1.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) instead of plain [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), because derived `JFormattedTextField` knows `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance` for example

```
myFormattedTextField.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
myFormattedTextField.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
myFormattedTextField.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

but little bit complicated to set/getValue

- for set is there `myFormattedTextField.setValue()`
- for get is there `((((Number) myFormattedTextField.getValue()).doubleValue()))`

don't use depreciated Java Desktop Aplications and its GroupLayout, sometime is so hard to place JComponenets correctly inside Container, use another and proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

don't add ActionListener to the `JTextField`, use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cast te parsed `double` into `int`, losing the fraction:

```
double principalLoan = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField3.getText())));
double loanInterest = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField1.getText())));
double loanTerm = (int)((Double.parseDouble(tempTextField2.getText())));
```

Just remove the casting and it should be OK:

```
double principalLoan = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField3.getText());
double loanInterest = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField1.getText());
double loanTerm = Double.parseDouble(tempTextField2.getText());
```